# Screen within Docker from ssh

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, gnu-screen

I have a Docker container running in an AWS EC2 instance I ssh into the EC2 instance, I run my docker container, and within the docker container I run a script with a `screen` session detached:

```
screen -dmS test my_script.sh
```

Within the same terminal I have no problem doing `screen -x test`.

However, if I now open a new terminal, SSH into the EC2 instance, go into the docker container (`sudo docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash`)  and run `screen -x test` I will get the error:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

The output of `screen -ls` shows:

```
There is a screen on:
    2122.test   (11/18/2016 09:45:50 AM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

And therefore I cannot access the screen from anywhere else. Any help here is appreciated. Thanks!

**NOTE**: I saw many similar questions on Google and SO, but none of the replies I could understand/try worked for my setup.

Comment: So you are trying to access a screen inside the container from outside the container?

Comment: @R0MANARMY Inside the container. Sorry, I edited the question, I saw it is not clear.